# MySQL Workbench GUI connection failure

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to interface with a remote database. When I configure the settings for the connection and click 'Test Connection', it displays a success dialog. Furthermore, if I right click the connection and select 'Start Command Line Client', everything is golden.

However, when I click the connection to use the GUI it displays a failure dialog 'Cannot Connect to Database Server'.

How might I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you get any error code with that error message?

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute following commands using MySQL command line:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.user;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
```

If you cannot execute those without any error, that means you have a permission problem with your user.

May be your problem is the same problem mentioned here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50024

Comment: Yes, I get that error when trying `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.user`. However granting my user all permissions does not fix the issue.

Comment: I think you have done this, but to be sure, check again whether you have granted relevant rights for the user for your current IP.  If your current machine (which you have installed MySQL work-bench) IP is 123.23.23.34 and your MySQL user is root, you need to grant  permissions for root@123.23.23.34. You might have already seen about that in the previously provided link.